# Correlate 3 variables with a list 2

Tags: java, list

Sorry for double posting but I need this topic running since my previous question was put on hold and it's been so for an hour please consider this question, thank you.

I'm trying to add 3 variables: 2 strings and a double to a List and make them correspond to each other. Say, I input 1 string and get a double or another String. Now, how do I do that since the List can actually hold 1 variable? or how can I make these 3 variables correspond to each other using List and possibly other methods?

For example: `Steve Jobs 2050.5` where Steve is `a`, Jobs is `b` and 2050.5 is `c`. I input Jobs or Steve it gives me 2050.5.

Here is the code so far:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Object> {

String filename = "people.txt";
private String surname;
private String firstName;
private double salary;

private List<Person> list;

public Person(String Surname, String FirstName, double Salary){
    surname = Surname;
    firstName = FirstName;
    salary = Salary;
}

public void makeList(){
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        Scanner scan = null;
        String fn = "";
        String sn = "";
        double s = 0;
        while(line != null){
            scan = new Scanner(line);
            sn = scan.next().toString();
            fn = scan.next().toString();
            s = scan.nextInt();
            check(sn);
            check(fn);
            checkd(s);
            // Methods to add
            System.out.println("Surname: " + sn +" First Name: "+ fn + " Salary:"+ s);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found: " + filename);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Can't read file: " + filename);
    }
}

public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    return 0;
}

public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public double getSalary(){
    return salary;
}

public void check(String m) {
    try {
        if (m == null) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong lines: " + filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: We aren't going to help you until you show some effort.

Comment: 3 variables 1 string get double 1 variable....whaaaaaat???

Comment: Your first question was closed because nobody could figure out what your question was. You've just reposted the same question.  You need to provide examples of what you're trying to accomplish, show the code you have written so far and explain what the code does that is incorrect.  I _strongly_ suggest you read the [FAQ] and [Ask], then come back and edit this question so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here's my guess at your objective: You have chunks of related data consisting of, say 2 strings and a number (double).  You want to create a list containing instances of these 3-element objects.  Am I close?

Comment: No seriously. I've got 2 strings say `a` and `b` and a double `c` and I want correlate them using List. For example: "Steve Jobs 2050.5" where Steve is `a`, Jobs is `b` and 2050.5 is `c`. I input Jobs or Steve it gives me 2050.5. How do I do that? I can also a have "Bill Gates 30.7" and "G Z 1.1" as many of these as I want.

Comment: You need to define a class to hold the related elements (i.e. an object that contains "Steve", "Jobs" and 2050.5). Then you need to put these objects into three multi-maps that will let you search on any attribute value.

Comment: Here's the way SO works: 1) You write some code to solve your problem; 2) It doesn't do what you want; 3) You ask a specific question and show us your work; 4) We help you.  What we generally don't do is write the code for you.

Comment: And the example save the understanding. You just have to show us what you have done so far! We will not do your home work or some contest you are in, given your hush to do this.

Comment: Fix your old question. Your question was put on hold for a reason and we don't care when your deadline is. This is among the rudest things you can do on SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a direct repost of OP's earlier question.

Comment: Added my code and examples what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1) Focus on what's essential to the problem. It appears that the data structure is what's most important, not the file I/O part. So forget about the I/O part for now.

2) Separate the `Person` from the data structure that contains the people. Those are different things.

3) Think about what the interface for the data structure would be. I think it's something like this though I'm not positive I fully understand the requirement here:

```
public interface PersonLookup {

    void add(Person person);

    Set<Person> get(String key); 
}

public class Person {
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private Double salary;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Double salary) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    ... getters ...

    ... equals() and hashCode() ...
}
```

4) Keep in mind the following questions: what happens if two people have the same first name or the same last name? What happens if somebody's first name is the same as somebody's last name? When doing the lookup, does the client need to indicate whether the name is a first vs. last name, or does the client simply specify a name and then the data structure has to search both first and last names? Your answers to the questions will impact not only the data structure implementation but also the interface. (Hint: think about why I used a `Set` above.)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything (excludes int, float..) is object in java, you can use List of Objects. Primitive variables will be wrapped with autoboxing into Integer, Float, but while manipulating with the data you still have to control the datatype of object witch you are manipulating with.. so I suggest you to create custom class with 3 fields or convert everything into string and use List of Strings instead.